# How to start building a topology for Storm?

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-storm, topology

I just installed storm-incubator in my Ubuntu 14.04. Now I can't get any related info to start off with building a topology and running it in Storm. Please can someone give me a step to step to what to do at this point? Like any clue to start off.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is google-able. There are a lot of resources online. And books of course.
Storm official documentation is the start.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [storm-starter project](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) on GitHub.

I would recommend getting Eclipse and Maven setup first, then clone the storm-starter project, and check out the Java portions of the code.

Another great example of some bolts is the [storm-hdfs](https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-hdfs) project which has some good tips as well.

Comment: @Chris The question seems to be on topic to me (fairly broad but that could be resolved with an edit). Since the question isn't closed and in the interest of helping I think answering is appropriate.